# Is it a good practise to have a subscription in every child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a parent container component and a lot of child components inside this parent container. Every child component is a tile, which renders piece of information. Each tile has subscription on a store and it observes for a boolean value. So is it a good practise, that there are so many subscriptions? Or is it better to have one subscription in the parent component which will pass information via `@Input` to each component?

Comment: If each child component is subscribing to the same source observable to get the same information, it's better off to handle the subscription in the parent (either subscribe in the controller or through `async` pipe in the template) and pass it on to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better for cleaner code to have one subscription in parent and pass information from parent component.

Comment: This is true…most of the time. There can be trade-offs to this kind of architecture, especially if your component tree starts to grow in depth and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

We use Input and Output Decorators to Pass information from one Component to Another like Parent and Child.`@Input/@Output` API will not help you everywhere. You have to manage in parent and child, if you want two way communication. Later, over the time it becomes complex to manage. Other downsides are that you can't do sibling to sibling data sharing. What if (for some unforeseen reason) you'd like tiles to share data? So I would prefer subscriptions.

My rule of thumb is, that if is anything but 1-2 simple data pieces I will setup subscription using `| async` pipe. And if I forsee using data in template more than 1-2 places I will use regular `subscribe()` - otherwise you will end up with too many places in template where you need to unpack the data. Then finally I decide if subscription should be something special. Like an `BehaviourSubject` which always emits something or `ReplaySubject`, which emits when it has something. I like to move subscriptions to their related services. Keeping so called business logic (data manipulation) at the service level. Then I know myself that all logic is in service, and everything related to what user sees is at component level - like it should be. Also helps when some backend guys come checking the code for some reason it would make more sense to them.

If you find yourself having too many subscriptions, which can happen also quite fast you could concat your data to a more complex object. You keep your data object up-to-data and on data change, emit this data object to all subscribers which read out only information that concerns them.

Other obvious end result is cleaner code. Few lines of subscription data vs many lines of @Inputs/@Ouputs in typescript code, in html in one or many components. When using subscriptions you can also then take full advantage god-ness that rxjs offers.

`tl;dr prefer subscriptions over Input/Output.`

Comment: Strongly disagree. Container/presenter architecture is very clean in most circumstances. Container speaks to services, uses `async` to subscribe and pass data down to children. If you're using the same Observable in multiple places in the same template and for some reason can't group them in an ngIf'd container, simply add shareReplay to the base Observable and hey presto, only one instance.

Comment: Intriguing - which part(s) do you disagree with? Because what's what I was trying to explain. Components taking data from a service with subscriptions rather than just face value of an @Input/@Output.

Comment: Container takes data with subscriptions (almost always `async`, please let's all stop using `subscribe()` unless it's absolutely necessary), drops data to children via their inputs and listens to their events through their outputs. This allows you to separate service communication logic from display logic.

Comment: @WillAlexander Thanks for the tip. I was having this challenge last night where my form needed to be disabled as I was saving. Did not want to } async for each control, so I tapped to a local var and used that. ShareReplay does the trick.